# Limit Scrolling to Content Area

Tags: vuex, vue-router, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

##### Problem:

I'm unable to limit scrolling to the content area of a typical Vue 3 SPA (scroll bar should not extend into header and footer areas). The Header and Footer blocks are placed with the Bootstrap `fixed-top` and `fixed-bottom` classes. It's a little hard to see in the attached image, but the current content area extends behind the header and footer. The header and footer are built from the Bootstrap components library. I can fix the content visibility with padding, but that doesn't address the overflow (scrollbar) issue.

[image: Content Area with Scrollbar]

##### Actions Taken

I've tried many solutions to similar questions, but those solutions have generally applied to earlier versions of Vue and Bootstrap and don't seem to work for me. I'm able to generate my desired layout in vanilla html and Bootstrap--it seems like it's the Vue 3 injection process that's tripping me up. I've tried applying layouts to both index.html and App.vue without success (trying both Bootstrap classes and vanilla css). The Bootstrap dependency appears to be working properly, so I don't think that's the issue (Bootstrap 5 not Bootstrap-Vue).

##### Desired Outcome:

Limit scrolling to content area while keeping header and footer Navbars fixed to their positions (and visible at all times).

##### Environment

Code snippets are used for readability (won't run in place). The below code has all (or nearly all) placement attempts stripped since they didn't work.

###### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="../public/favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <!--    <script>window.scrollTo(0,1) // this is meant to hide the address bar in mobile Safari on page load.</script>-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>The <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>

    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files are auto injected here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

###### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="wrapper" class="m-1">
    <div id="header_area">
      <Header/>
    </div>
    <div id="content_area">
      <span class="page-title">{{ title }}</span>
      <hr class="border-secondary">
      <span class="page-content">{{ content }}</span>
      <router-view @page-data="updatePageName($event)"/>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_area">
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/Header.vue'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
    title: "home",
    content: ""
    }
  },
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
  },
  methods: {
    updatePageName: function(event) {
      this.title = event.title;
      this.content = event.content;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
  @import'~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
  @import "./assets/main.css";
</style>
```

###### Header.vue (partial)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="Header navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark border-bottom border-4 fixed-top" aria-label="Header Bar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <router-link to="/"><span class="navbar-brand">brand</span>  </router-link>
        <button class="navbar-toggler btn-sm" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#Navbar" aria-controls="Navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-sm-0">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <router-link to=""><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">pages</a></router-link>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdown01" id="dave">
              
              [snip]
```

###### main.css

```css
@charset "utf-8";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato-Light';
    src: local('Lato-Light'), url('Lato-Light.ttf') format("truetype");
}

:root {
    --background: #191919;
    --dark: #000000;
    --grey1: #111111;
    --grey2: #222222;
    --grey3: #333333;
    --grey4: #444444;
    --grey5: #555555;
    --grey6: #666666;
    --grey7: #777777;
    --grey8: #888888;
    --grey9: #999999;
    --light: #FFFFFF;
}


html, body {
    background-color: var(--dark) !important;
    color: var(--light) !important;
}

a {
    color: var(--bs-secondary) !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    font-family: Lato-Light, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

button {
    padding: 1px;
}

input {
    border: solid 1px var(--grey9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    text-align: start;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-item {
    border: solid 1px var(--bs-dark);
    color: var(--bs-secondary) !Important;
    /*font-size: 0.9rem;*/
    width: 94%;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: var(--bs-dark) !important;
    border: solid 1px var(--bs-secondary);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 94%;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: var(--bs-dark) !important;
    border: solid 1px var(--bs-dark) !important;
    color: var(--bs-secondary) !Important;
    /*font-size: 0.9rem !important;*/
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    border: solid 1px var(--bs-dark) !important;
    color: var(--bs-secondary) !Important;
    /*font-size: 0.9rem !important;*/
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}

.navbar {
    border-bottom-color: var(--dark) !important;
    border-top-color: var(--dark) !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    border: solid 1px var(--bs-dark);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--bs-secondary) !important;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
    border: solid 1px var(--bs-secondary);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-link {
    background-color: var(--bs-dark) !important;
    border: solid 1px var(--bs-dark);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--bs-secondary) !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    border: solid 1px var(--bs-secondary);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-link.dropdown-toggle {
    padding: 8px;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    border: solid 1px var(--grey5) !important;
    color: var(--bs-secondary) !Important;
    display: block;
}

.page-title {
    color: var(--grey5);
    font-size: 2rem !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}

.page-content {

}

.selected {
    border-color: lime !important;
}

#app {

}

#header_area {

}

#content_area {

}

#footer_area {

}


#Footer {
     font-size: 0.9em;
}


:focus {
    border-color: var(--dark);
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a pure CSS issue and should have nothing to do with Vue as you have full control over the content, e.g. CSS grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @Thomas Thanks.  I've tried straight css grid without success, but I'll have another go.

Comment: @Thomas Took me a while, but I was able to get CSS Grid to work.  Thank you for putting me on the path.  If you choose to write an answer, I will accept it.  Cheers!

Comment: I am more of a coder and less familiar with CSS, so I probably wouldn't be able to provide an answer for it.

Comment: @Thomas - Understood. I will go ahead and accept my own answer then. Thanks again for the help.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to get the CSS Grid spec to work. **For my situation, adding styles to `<html>` and `<body>` in `index.html` was important,** but may not be required.  Assigning `!Important` to the grid elements may also not be required, but was done for insurance.

Now, any content that is injected by the Vue Router will appear in `content_area` and *only* that section will scroll (as needed).

###### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="app m-1">

    <div id="header_area">
      <Header/>
    </div>

    <div id="content_area">
      <span class="page-title">{{ title }}</span>
      <hr class="border-secondary">
      <span class="page-content">{{ content }}</span>
      <router-view @page-data="updatePageName($event)"/>
    </div>

    <div id="footer_area">
      <Footer/>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/components/Header.vue'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
    title: "home",
    content: ""
    }
  },
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
  },
  methods: {
    updatePageName: function(event) {
      this.title = event.title;
      this.content = event.content;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
  @import'~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
  @import "./assets/navbar.css";
  @import "./assets/main.css";
</style>
```

###### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="margin: 0;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="../public/favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <noscript>
      <strong>The <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>

    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files are auto-injected here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

###### main.css

```css
.app {
    height: 100vh !important;
    display: grid !important;
    grid-gap: 5px !important;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr !important;
    grid-template-rows: 65px 1fr 40px !important;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer" !important;
}

#header_area {
    grid-area: header !important;
}

#content_area {
    grid-area: content !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
}

#footer_area {
    grid-area: footer !important;
}
```

##### Plain HTML example

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 70px 1fr 40px;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
}

.H {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.C {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.F {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="H">header</div>
    <div class="C">
      content
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br> .
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="F">footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```